# push VC while dismissing previous two presented VCs

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have VC1 that is in navigation controller, we are presented VC2 from VC1, then VC3 from VC2. When I click button in VC3, I need to dismiss VC2 and VC3, after which push VC4 to the VC1

So this
VC1 (presented modally)-> VC2 (presented modally)-> VC3
to this
VC1 (pushed to navigation controller)-> VC4

I tried everything but nothing works

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question. If you think it will help others, please post a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is the method of closing vc2 when vc1 -> vc2 and entering vc3 from vc1.
The second is a method that goes the way you want.
Do you want to run it?

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    func popAndPushViewController(goto: UIViewController) {
        if var vcArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            vcArray.removeLast()
            vcArray.append(goto)
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray, animated: true)
        }
    }


    func doublePopAndPushViewController(goto: UIViewController) {
        if var vcArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            vcArray.removeLast()
            vcArray.removeLast()
            vcArray.append(goto)
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

```
let nextViewController = UIViewController()
self.doublePopAndPushViewController(goto: nextViewController)
```